# How do I extend the virsh/qemu/libvirt Timeout?

Tags: timeout, qemu, libvirt, kvm-virtualization

There's a known issue with starting virtual machines with large hard drive images. Apparently, the time-out is 3 seconds, but in reality, it can take up to 15 seconds for a machine to start. I've read several bug reports, and people confirming it's a time-out problem, but I have yet to see a solution.

Is there an option I can pass, like:

```
virsh start MyMachine --ignore-timeout
```

Or a config file that needs changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you see unexpected behavior with an Open Source product like `libvirt`, the best thing you can do is file a Bug in respective bug tracking systems such as [Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/) or [Launchpad](https://launchpad.net/). 
Otherwise, since it's Open Source, you can edit the code, find the timeout setting and tweak it

Comment: There's several places where the bug is reported, but no fix listed. I'm not sure I'm comfortable (re)compiling, since the machine is a production server, and working OK aside from this glitch. I can't believe there's no configuration option...

Comment: Actually, libvirt and virsh are (AFAIK) python scripts. That means no compilation is required if you go into the code.

Comment: Do you know where the actual scripts reside? (Ubuntu 9.04)

Comment: I use Fedora, and in order to get the code I had to install libvirt-devel. As I can see, there is some C involved (virsh is binary and not bytecoded) but still, rpm -ql or even a simple find command can show you the files. I'm sure aptitude has a similar set of commands

Answer (score -1):

virsh -k0 start MyMachine 
should work for you.

Comment: a) This needs more explanation. b) This question is 7 years old. Does your answer apply to `virsh` anno 2009?

Comment: This post edited in 2015.
-k0 , disable keepalive.

to completely disable time out on child connection
go to  ./src/qemu/qemu_monitor.c
qemuMonitorOpenUnix
and change 
 int timeout  from 30 to new limit.